# Ping IP address , 4 Replies

Tags: ping, icmp

why when ping an IP address we get 4 replies ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ping is just a small program which sends ICMP Echo Requests, and receives the ICMP Echo Replies. Actually, many different implementations of ping exist...

On Windows, the default ping utility sends 4 echo request by default. So, when everything is working fine, you will see 4 echo replies. You can send more (or less) requests by passing the `-n` option to the ping executable.

On Unix systems, the default implementation will keep sending echo requests until  interrupted by the user (with Ctrl-C), and the option to send a specific number of requests is `-c`.

Answer (score 2):

I will assume you're using a Windows PC.

When you "ping," your computer sends (by default) four ICMP echo requests.   Each request will get a reply (if everything is working properly).  So you see each of the four replies.  You can change the number of echo requests with the "-n" switch.

Comment: Why it sends 4 requests ?

Comment: That's just the way the program works.  I assume it's so you will see several values of response time, rather than a single data point.